# Durandal TodoMVC - Cannot write a value to a ko.computed

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module, durandal, todomvc

I'm trying to build a version of the todo app using [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/) (including [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) + [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)) from a [TodoMVC template](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc). I realize that a todo app doesn't really show off the features of Durandal, but I'm on the learning path and figured it would be a good first project.

Anyway, in the process I've stumbled upon an error that I'm unable to solve (see below).

```
Error("Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.")
```

I've also attached an image that shows these in the console.

[image: ko.computed errors]

You can find the source code at https://github.com/robksawyer/durandal-todo. The todo viewmodel is located at https://github.com/robksawyer/durandal-todo/blob/master/viewmodels/todos.js.

**Update:** Most of the Knockout code is borrowed from the Knockout+Require TodoMVC project at https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/labs/dependency-examples/knockoutjs_require/

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you try the suggestions in the error message?

Comment: I should have caveated that the Knockout code in my project is borrowed from an existing TodoMVC version (https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/labs/dependency-examples/knockoutjs_require/). This version uses Knockout + Require, so the code, in theory, should be similar to the code that I should use, right? I haven't updated any of the code for the ko.computeds because of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're misreading the console.

For example, "allCompleted" is a property on your view model, which is declared as a dependent observable (i.e. a "computed"):

```
// writeable computed observable to handle marking all complete/incomplete
self.allCompleted = ko.computed({
    // -- trimmed --
});
```

What you're seeing in the console isn't the `Cannot write a value` error; it's the debug output for a `computed` property - i.e. its function definition. For reference, here's the function definition of a dependent observable straight from the [knockout (2.2.1) source](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.debug.js):

```
function dependentObservable() {
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        if (typeof writeFunction === "function") {
            // Writing a value
            writeFunction.apply(evaluatorFunctionTarget, arguments);
        } else {
            throw new Error("Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.");
        }
        return this; // Permits chained assignments
    } else {
        // Reading the value
        if (!_hasBeenEvaluated)
            evaluateImmediate();
        ko.dependencyDetection.registerDependency(dependentObservable);
        return _latestValue;
    }
}
```

What you're seeing in your console is the minified version of this code.

If you want to see the *value* that's returned by the property you'd have to invoke it.

Comment: Ok, let's forget I even mentioned it. ;) Thanks for the detailed response.